# Prove that the free module over $R$ generated by a single element is isomorphic to $R$ as a module over itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Prove that the free module over $R$ generated by a single element is
>   isomorphic to $R$ as a module over itself

By a free module over $R$ we mean a module $F$ together with a function $f$, over a set $R$, such that for every $g:R\to X$, being $X$ a module, we have a unique homomorphism $h$ such that $g = h\circ f$.

What is a module $R$ over itself? It should be the module $R$ such that $R$ is a group and the ring that multiplies it is also $R$?

Ok, so I need to show a bijection between $F$ and $R$, right?

I'm thinking in picking $X$ as $F$ too, and then $h$ is a homomorphism, maybe it helps in proving isomorphism, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't see why $R^2$ should be isomorphic to $R$ as a $R$-module.

Comment: @user1952009: O.P; said ‘generated by  a *single* element’.

Comment: @Bernard I'd say $R^2 \simeq R[{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ - 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}]$ as a $R$-module, right ?

Comment: Your definition of free module is wrong. To say that a module is free over $R$ you need to be specific about the set on which it is free (i.e, the basis). So your definition must be something like this. A module $M$ together with an (injective) map $f:S\rightarrow M$ is said to be free over $S$ if for every module $N$ and map $g:S\rightarrow N$ there is a unique homomorphism $\bar{g}:M\rightarrow N$ such that $g=\bar{g}\circ f$. Usually $S\subset M$ and $f$ is just the inclusion.

Comment: Now the problems asks you to take a free module $M$ over $S$ in which $\#S=1$ and to prove that $M\cong R$ (as $R$-modules) by taking an specific election of $g:S\rightarrow R$ in the above definition.

Comment: @user1952009: No. Your r.h.s. is just the set of matrices $\begin{bmatrix}0&r\\-r&0\end{bmatrix}$. Just  as if all complex numbers had opposite real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @Bernard I was thinking to a ring generated by $R$ and a single other element $a$ and being a free $R$-module. You are saying a $R$-module generated by a single element has a different meaning ?

Comment: Yes:; What you were thinking of the free $R$-algebra on the set   with a single element, a.k.a. polynomial ring with coefficient in $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $R$ is a free module over itself with generating set $\{1\}$. Now suppose that $\{a\}$ is the generating set for $F$ over $R$. Then the $R$-linear module homomorphism $\phi : F \to R$ defined by $a \mapsto 1$ can easily be shown to be bijective, and hence an isomorphism of modules.